# Strange mongo shell behavior on meteor.com: enter key is stuck?

Tags: meteor

I can connect successfully to my mongodb shell on meteor.com, but as soon as I get a prompt it is as if I hold down the enter key (which I do not...). The output below was produced by logging in and then pressin Ctrl-C after half a second. Any pointers?

```
mongodb://client:84a38acd-9ac1-e8dc-9ed8-f0cc43c23647@production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/XXXXXXXXX_com
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
connecting to: production-db-a1.meteor.io:27017/XXXXXXXXXX_com
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
^CWed Jul  3 21:24:01.937   Assertion failure isABSONObj() src/mongo/db/../bson/bson-inl.h 183
0x1000ec22b 0x1000caadc 0x100083311 0x10000f2ca 0x100001755 0x7fff9321894a 0x101018210 0x1000e11fc 0x1000e1841 0x1000e1bd8 0x100044cfe 0x100044f4d 0x10006a9aa 0x1000427c0 0x10004e222 0x1000c4b87 0x1000af44d 0xab67c34c4db 0xab67c3485c2 
 0   mongo                               0x00000001000ec22b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongo                               0x00000001000caadc _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 284
 2   mongo                               0x0000000100083311 _ZNK5mongo11BSONElement14embeddedObjectEv + 193
 3   mongo                               0x000000010000f2ca _ZNK5mongo11shell_utils18ConnectionRegistry30killOperationsOnAllConnectionsEb + 524
 4   mongo                               0x0000000100001755 _Z10quitNicelyi + 85
 5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff9321894a _sigtramp + 26
 6   ???                                 0x0000000101018210 0x0 + 4311843344
 7   mongo                               0x00000001000e11fc _ZN5mongo13MessagingPort4recvERNS_7MessageE + 112
 8   mongo                               0x00000001000e1841 _ZN5mongo13MessagingPort4recvERKNS_7MessageERS1_ + 33
 9   mongo                               0x00000001000e1bd8 _ZN5mongo13MessagingPort4callERNS_7MessageES2_ + 52
Wed Jul  3 21:24:01.941 terminate() called in shell, printing stack:
```

Comment: are you still experiencing this weird behavior?

Comment: yes, just checked. Still there. Like my enter key is stuck.